# How do I Access My Swift Singleton from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a Swift class:

```
@objc
public class MZAActiveState: NSObject {
    @objc static let privateSharedInstance = MZAActiveState()
..
    @objc
    public class func shared() -> MZAActiveState {
        return privateSharedInstance
    }
    @objc var color: UIColor? = .red
}
```

In my Objective-C class I have included the Swift header (and the Singleton and its "shared" method is declared in this file):

```
#import "SketchWorkshop-Swift.h"
```

and I refer to the static shared instance in a method:

```
- (void) doSomething:(id)sender
{
        [self.colorPickerController setInitialColor:[MZAActiveState shared].color];

}
```

I get no compiler warnings or build errors, but the color does not get set. If I place a breakpoint on the line and type:

> (lldb) po [MZAActiveState shared].color;

I get this:

> error: use of undeclared identifier ‘MZAActiveState'

I would expect to be able to see [MZAActiveState shared], since it is static and exposed (I believe) to Objective-C.  What am I missing?

These links did not answer the question:

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949815/ios-cant-access-swift-singleton-from-objective-c),

[Another Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24489075/call-a-swift-singleton-from-objective-c),

[Here's a Third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432122/cant-log-swift-singletons-from-objective-c-in-xcode-console)

Comment: Did you set any value for `color`? If not, `[MZAActiveState shared].color` will be `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a nil color

```
@objc var color: UIColor?
```

to

```
@objc var color: UIColor = UIColor.red
```

It's worth saying that objective-c doesn't respond to nil settings and doesn't crash at all

Comment: Thanks for responding. I assigned a value to the color in the initializer, but still get the same results. The code I posted is a simplified extract. I'll flesh out my example after trying a few more things.

Comment: I have created this demo https://github.com/ShKhan9/ObjcSwift it does the same job

Comment: Thank you. You have proved that my problem lies elsewhere. Upvoted and accepted.